# Plotting multi-dimensional true and predicted arrays in a regression task

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, regression

In a regression task of predicting 1 hour power load in the future using LSTM (univariate LSTM), the results can be plotted easily something like this:

```
plt.plot(y_ts, label='True Future', color='blue')
plt.plot(y_pred, label='Forecast', color='red')
plt.show()
```

This is because both `y_ts` and `y_pred` are 1D. Now, assuming that the task has changed to predict 6 hours power load in the future using LSTM. This means `y_ts` and `y_pred` are going to be now in 2D, for instance `y_ts= (3454, 6)` and `y_pred= (3454, 6)` How do I plot this case of high dimensional array?

Comment: Use some dimension technique, e.g. tSNE, to reduce the dimension to 2 and plot them. Or you can use parallel coordinate or radar plots.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean applying dimension reduction on the `y_pred` and `y_ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally there is only one dimension in your data i.e. time; what you have are 6 time slices - it would make sense to append them to each other, plot on the same axes and mark each hour separately.

Let me explain this with the help of some fabricated data:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)

n, h = 3454, 6
y_ts, y_pred = np.random.randn(n, h).cumsum(), np.random.randn(n, h).cumsum()
y_ts = y_ts - np.min(y_ts)
y_pred = y_ts - (y_pred - np.min(y_pred)) / np.max(y_pred) * 0.05 * np.mean(y_ts)
y_ts = y_ts.reshape((n, h), order="F")
y_pred = y_pred.reshape((n, h), order="F")
```

Plotting y_ts individually (and similarly for y_pred):

```
for i in range(h):
    plt.plot(y_ts[:, i], label=f'y_ts_h{i+1}')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, you can straighten your data and plot it as a 1-D series as shown below:

```
y_ts = y_ts.reshape((n*h), order="F")
y_pred = y_pred.reshape((n*h), order="F")
plt.plot(y_ts, label=f'y_ts')
plt.plot(y_pred, label=f'y_pred')

for i in range(h):
    plt.axvline(x=(n*(i+1)), c='m')

plt.xticks([(i+1)*n for i in range(h)], [f'hr_{i+1}' for i in range(h)])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Well explained! Thank you very much.